# How to import a variable from another class in java

Tags: android

I'm want to register a user in `Cloud Firestore`, for that i have 2 diferent screens in Android Studio (`FormCadastro1` and `FormCadastro2`) the problem is import the selected item of every spinner in `FormCadastro1` and bring then to `FormCadastro2`, and then send then to Cloud Firestore.

I'm thinking about to import class `FormCadastro1` to `FormCadastro2`, if there is another way to do it please tell me.

FormCadastro1

```
   public class FormCadastro1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner edit_spempr, edit_sparea, edit_spsetor, edit_spcargos;
    Button bt_cadastrar;
    Usuarios usuarios;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_cadastro1);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        IniciarComponentes();


        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spItemCargos, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        edit_spcargos.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spItemEmpresa, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        edit_spempr.setAdapter(adapter1);

        ArrayAdapter adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spItemArea, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        edit_sparea.setAdapter(adapter3);

        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spItemSetor, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        edit_spsetor.setAdapter(adapter2);

         String Empr = edit_spempr.getSelectedItem().toString();
         String Area = edit_sparea.getSelectedItem().toString();
         String Setor = edit_spsetor.getSelectedItem().toString();
         String Cargo = edit_spcargos.getSelectedItem().toString();


        usuarios = new Usuarios();
        bt_cadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(FormCadastro1.this, FormCadastro2.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });




    }

    private void IniciarComponentes() {

        edit_sparea = findViewById(R.id.spArea);
        edit_spempr = findViewById(R.id.spEmpresa);
        edit_spsetor = findViewById(R.id.spSetor);
        edit_spcargos = findViewById(R.id.spCargos);
        bt_cadastrar = findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);

    }


}
```

FormCadastro 2

```
public class FormCadastro2 extends AppCompatActivity{


        EditText edit_nome, edit_senha, edit_email, edit_confsenha, edit_tel;
        Button bt_Próximo;
        String[] mensagens = {"Preencha todos os campos", "Cadastro realizado com sucesso"};
        String UID;
        String ID;
        TextView MainActivityPasswordError, MainActivityConfirmPassError;
        Usuarios usuarios;
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();



        //1.Qual layout será exibido
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_cadastro2);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();


            IniciarComponentes();
            usuarios = new Usuarios();
            CollectionReference reff = db.collection("Usuarios");
            bt_Próximo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //3.1.Convertendo o texto em string ao clicar no botão
                    String nome = edit_nome.getText().toString().trim();
                    String email = edit_email.getText().toString().trim();
                    String senha = edit_senha.getText().toString().trim();
                    String tel = edit_tel.getText().toString().trim();


                    //3.2.Tratando exceções
                    if (nome.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || senha.isEmpty() || tel.isEmpty()) {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, mensagens[0], Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.setBackgroundTint(Color.WHITE);
                        snackbar.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        snackbar.show();

                    } else {

                        CadastrarUsuario(view);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(FormCadastro2.this, FormLogin.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                }
            });

        }


        public void SalvarDadosUsuario() {

            String nome = edit_nome.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = edit_email.getText().toString().trim();
            String senha = edit_senha.getText().toString().trim();
            String tel = edit_tel.getText().toString().trim();
            String empresa = //edit_spempresa selected item
            String area = //edit_sparea selected item
            String setor = //edit_spsetor selected item
            String cargo = //edit_spcargos selected item


            UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

            //5.2.Cria a variável
            Map<String, Object> usuarios = new HashMap<>();
            usuarios.put("nome", nome);
            usuarios.put("email", email);
            usuarios.put("senha", senha);
            usuarios.put("Tel", tel);
            usuarios.put("empresa", empresa);
            usuarios.put("area", area);
            usuarios.put("setor", setor);
            usuarios.put("cargo", cargo);
            usuarios.put("Login", UID);
            usuarios.put("ID", "");

            db.collection("Usuarios").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Integer IDS = task.getResult().size();

                        DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("Usuarios").document(ID = String.valueOf(IDS + 1));
                        documentReference.set(usuarios);

                        db.collection("Usuarios").document(ID).update("ID", ID);

                    }
                }
            });

        }


        private void IniciarComponentes() {

            edit_nome = findViewById(R.id.editNome);
            edit_email = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
            edit_senha = findViewById(R.id.editSenha);
            edit_confsenha = findViewById(R.id.editConfSenha);
            edit_tel = findViewById(R.id.editTel);
            bt_Próximo = findViewById(R.id.btnPróximo);


        }

        private boolean ValidaçãoDeSenha() {
            String passwordInput = edit_senha.getText().toString().trim();
            String ConfitmpasswordInput = edit_confsenha.getText().toString().trim();
            if (passwordInput.isEmpty()) {
                MainActivityPasswordError.setText("Field can't be empty");
                return false;
            }
            if (passwordInput.length() < 5) {
                MainActivityPasswordError.setText("Password must be at least 5 characters");
                return false;
            }
            if (!passwordInput.equals(ConfitmpasswordInput)) {
                MainActivityConfirmPassError.setText("Password Would Not be matched");
                return false;
            } else {
                MainActivityConfirmPassError.setText("Password Matched");
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void CadastrarUsuario(View view) {
            String email = edit_email.getText().toString();
            String senha = edit_senha.getText().toString();

            //4.1.FirebaseAuth coletando as informações necessárias para o cadastro e as autenticando
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    //4.2.Caso a tarefa seja completa
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        //4.3.Oque vai acontecer
                        SalvarDadosUsuario();

                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, mensagens[1], Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.setBackgroundTint(Color.WHITE);
                        snackbar.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else {
                        //4.4.Criando String erro
                        String erro;

                        try {
                            throw task.getException();

                        } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                            erro = "Digite um senha com no mínimo  6 carácteres";
                        } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                            erro = "Esta conta já foi cadastrada";
                        } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                            erro = "E-mail inválido";
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            erro = "Erro ao cadastrar usuário";
                        }

                        //4.5.Cor da mensagem
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, erro, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.setBackgroundTint(Color.WHITE);
                        snackbar.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        snackbar.show();

                    }

                }


            });
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the values from FormCadastro1 to [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles) when are you launching FormCadastro2 and retrieve those when it will launch.

Important: passing data should be fully  serializable and less then 1MB